# how can i transform this object in to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach

Hi I have this object and I want to loop over this object with a forEach but I can't, how can I transform it into an array? Sorry for my ignorance but is this a json object?

```
{
  file0: {
    fieldName: 'file0',
    originalFilename: '4.png',
  },
  file1: {
    fieldName: 'file1',
    originalFilename: '1.jpg',
  },
  file2: {
    fieldName: 'file2',
    originalFilename: '2.jpg',
  },
  file3: {
    fieldName: 'file3',
    originalFilename: '3.png',
  }
}
```

The array would be something like this:

```
[
{},
{},
{},
{}
]
```

Comment: Use `Object.values()`

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which one of these do you need?

The one with just the objects or one with objects AND key?

```js
const obj = {
  file0: {
    fieldName: 'file0',
    originalFilename: '4.png',
  },
  file1: {
    fieldName: 'file1',
    originalFilename: '1.jpg',
  },
  file2: {
    fieldName: 'file2',
    originalFilename: '2.jpg',
  },
  file3: {
    fieldName: 'file3',
    originalFilename: '3.png',
  }
}

// fast
const arr1 = Object.values(obj).slice(0); // see below why I slice
console.log(arr1);

// alternative using map: 

const arr2 = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
console.log(arr2);

// include the key:

const arr3 = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({ [key]: obj[key] }));
console.log(arr3);

// Taking the Object.values directly, will POINT to the original object:
const arr4 = Object.values(obj);
arr4[0].fieldName = "XXX"
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: That was me. There was just a pile of code with a text like **pick any of two options for any reason** without comments/explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `map()` and get the desired result as below:

```
const obj = {
  file0: {
    fieldName: 'file0',
    originalFilename: '4.png',
  },
  file1: {
    fieldName: 'file1',
    originalFilename: '1.jpg',
  },
  file2: {
    fieldName: 'file2',
    originalFilename: '2.jpg',
  },
  file3: {
    fieldName: 'file3',
    originalFilename: '3.png',
  }
}

const arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key])
```

and get the following result:

```
[
{fieldName: "file0", originalFilename: "4.png"},
{fieldName: "file1", originalFilename: "1.jpg"},
{fieldName: "file2", originalFilename: "2.jpg"},
{fieldName: "file3", originalFilename: "3.png"}
]
```